# Duplicate value in list getting saved multiple times (Single record)

Tags: list, duplicates

I am trying to update SObject record depending on the crtieria, id it matches create a SObject variable and adding values and then finally adding this into a List.When a match is found the Sobject variable here'PRrecordupdate' gets created and values get assigend but as I add it in a list,the original value already present in the list is removed and this latest PRrecordupdate get saved multiple times.Please look into the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.Thanks

**//CODE**

```
 List<Domain_review__C> newPR = new List<Domain_review__C>();
List<Domain_review__C> PRCollectionupdate = new List<Domain_review__C>();
Domain_review__C PRrecordupdate = new Domain_review__C();  
map<id,domain_review__C> PRmap = new map<id,domain_review__C>();    

List<Domain_Review__c> PR  =  [Select id,name,Property_Name_text__c from Domain_Review__c Where Exchange_Quality_ID__c =: a0W56000002PgXfEAK];

        For(domain_review__c a: PR)
        {
            
            For(Domain_review__c b: newPR)
            
            {
                               
                if(a.Property_Name_text__c == b.property_text__c)
                {
                   
                    
                    PRrecordupdate.Id = a.Id;
                    PRrecordupdate.Approval_Status__c = b.Approval_Status__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.Rejection_Reason__c = b.Rejection_Reason__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.seller_name__c = b.seller_name__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.Inventory_Relationship__c = b.Inventory_Relationship__c;
                    
                    
                    PRCollectionupdate.add(PRrecordupdate);
//?? here, it's removing the earlier record and updating with new record multiple times, means at the end in PRCollectionupdate list only one record is saved multiple times//
                  

                }
                
            }

               }
     
        
       
       PRmap.putall(PRCollectionupdate);
      
if(PRmap.size()>0){
    update PRmap.values();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It got solved. The issue was with the Sobject variable not getting initialised